# Python tkinter does not finish the drawing

Tags: python, tkinter

i have to draw the house of santa claus with tkinter, but when using the following code it just stops after the first line

First I import turtle and open the gui screen

```
import turtle as t
t.Screen()
```

then i use this code

```
>>> s = 100
>>> points = [(s,0), (s,s), (0,0), (s,s), (s/2.,2.*s), (0,s), (s,0)]
>>> for p in points:
        t.goto(p)
        t.mainloop()
```

but it stops after the first line, how do i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is specified in the documentation for [`turtle.mainloop`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/turtle.html#turtle.mainloop):

> `turtle.mainloop()`
>
> Starts event loop - calling Tkinter’s mainloop function. Must **be the last statement in a turtle graphics program**. Must not be used if a script is run from within IDLE in -n mode (No subprocess) - **for interactive use** of turtle graphics

Here however it is not the last statement: it is called for each `point` in `points`. So you have to rewrite your program to:

```
for p in points:
    t.goto(p)

t.mainloop()
```

If you read the second boldface part of the specification, it is not even necessary to call it: your program is not interactive. So the following program will be sufficient:

```
import turtle as t
t.Screen()

for p in points:
    t.goto(p)
```